# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect on PHP for windows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'test');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'test');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'site');

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    OR die('Could not connect to MYSQL ' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

If I run this I will get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I'm using [PHP for Windows downloaded](https://windows.php.net/download)

From what I have read, you're supposed to uncomment parts in your php.ini file. There is no php.ini in my PHP folder, but only php.ini-development and php.ini-production.

I've tried renaming one of the files to php.ini and uncommenting `extension=mysqli`, but the problem is still there.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need to rename one of those to `php.ini`.

Comment: copy one of those files as php.ini and make the necessary changes.

Comment: At the command line, run command `php -m` (lists modules) and see if there is a mysqli in the output. (the output is alphabetically listed)

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue, and most stackoverflow answers didn't really clearly address this other step you need to take in setting up your php.ini. If you just uncomment `extension=mysqli` php still has no idea where any of your extensions are actually located, so it will fail to load them. Locate the section of your php.ini that looks something like:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

And then uncomment the bottom "extension_dir" value and fill in the value with the absolute path of your "ext" directory, ie:

```
extension_dir = "<absolute-path-to-ext-folder>"
```

Once I completed these two steps (uncommenting `extension=mysqli` and then adding the absolute path in extension_dir), mysqli loaded correctly

Comment: Thank you so very much. This saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

There are two files php.ini-development and php.ini-production 
There is no php.ini file in the php directory 
so you have to create one 
**Step1:** Copy the php.ini-development into new file named php.ini 
**Step2:** Uncomment `;extension=mysqli` by removing `;` from the starting of line ***no: 928***

**Step3:** Replace the ext with exact location of ext folder of php in line ***no:763*** `extension_dir = "ext"` **Ex:** `extension_dir = "C:/Program Files/php/ext"` and save the file
**Step4:** `php -m` run in terminal and look for `mysqli`, it its there then everything is working fine

Comment: It worked for windows

Answer (score 0):

As the setup say you have to rename one of those 2 you have, if you don't PHP will go with defaults.

So change one of them to php.ini and uncomment the line - this should not really be needed as far as i recall.

Comment: extension=mysqli is this the only thing i need to uncomment?

Comment: I think so. 
TBH  I can't remember, It been so long since I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**, you can find the file in the `C:\xampp\php\php.ini-Folder` (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).

**Under Linux**, most distributions put lampp under `/opt/lampp`, so the file can be found under `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`.

If you can't find it. Then you should rename one of those to php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the these two lines

> ;extension =mysqli
> Uncomment it
> Then find the folded ext that is in your php folder and copy as path

Locate the extension_dir and uncomment it then put the path there sample

```
extension_dir="C:/php/ext/"
```

Type in your cmd `php -m`  and check if mysqli is listed
You might want to include php in path

Answer (score 0):

I came cross this problem and resolved it. Here are my two cents.

My env: Win10 + Nginx + PHP8 + Mysql

Steps:

1. Copy php.ini-development or php.ini-production to php.ini.
2. Edit php.ini, uncomment & update these two items in php.ini according to your php installation directory.

```
extension_dir = "D:\php-8.2.11-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\ext"
...
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

3. Restart php-cgi.exe. For example:

```
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c D:\php-8.2.11-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
```

4. Create a test.php and put it in your web root. Access it in browser: http://localhost/test.php

```php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

5. On page test.php, search (Ctrl+F) for string "Loaded Configuration File". Make sure it's the php.ini you edited.
   If the value is "none", then maybe you start php-cgi.exe without a absolute path.
   (My problem is, I start php.cgi.exe in C:\Users\Administrator using cmd like: php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c php.ini . So the php.ini file couldn't be found and "Loaded Configuration File" is "none")
6. On page test.php, search for string "MysqlI Support" "Client API library version" and if they appear in your search result, then mysqli extension is correctly loaded and your problem should be resolved.

BTW, command "php --ini" may output the correct php.ini path but it doesn't ensure you start php-cgi.exe with the correct php.ini path.
My "php --ini" outputs the correct php.ini path, but still "Loaded Configuration File" is "none". It just because I start php-cgi.exe in dir "C:\Users\Administrator" instead of "D:\php-8.2.11-nts-Win32-vs16-x64".

Hope this helps.